# How do I conditionally format a cell in a row based on a match with the value in a specific column?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I use conditional formatting highlight cells in a range where the value in the cell matches the value in a specific column in the same row in Google Sheets.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: cond2]

This is the correct custom formula to apply to the range `B2:F`:

```
=and($a2=b2,$a2<>"")
```

[image: cond]

Answer (score 0):

To use conditional formatting to highlight cells in a range where the value in the cell matches the value in a specific column in the same row in Google Sheets, you can use a custom formula and the $ symbol to create a relative reference to the column you want to compare the cell's value to.

Here are the steps to do this:

- Select the range of cells that you want to apply the conditional
  formatting to.
- In the toolbar at the top of the page, click on the "Format" dropdown
  menu and select "Conditional formatting".
- In the "Conditional formatting" panel that appears on the right side
  of the page, click on the "Add a rule" button.
- In the "Format cells if" dropdown menu, select "Custom formula is".
- In the "Value or formula" field, enter the following formula,
  replacing "A" with the column letter you want to compare the cell's
  value to: =A2=A
- Use the "Formatting style" options to specify the formatting that
  should be applied to cells that match the condition in the formula.
- Click on the "Done" button to save the rule and apply the conditional
  formatting to your selected range.

Here is an example of how this formula might look in the "Conditional formatting" panel:

```
Format cells if:
Custom formula is: =A2=A
Formatting style: Bold
```

Comment: "you can use a custom formula and the $ symbol" 
 Where did you think you were using the `$` ?